# Trying to automate a Minecraft server

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I want the server to run everyday at 7 AM and end at 3 AM the following night. So I set some basic tasks with Task Scheduler and the Server Stop Task works fine and closes the server at its allotted time but whenever I try running the Server Start Task it opens the LaunchServer.bat and instead of loading chunks I get

> "Error: Unable to access jarfile
>   forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-universal.jar"

I don't get this error if I manually open the LaunchServer.Bat from the folder. Any fix?

What I'm supposed to get!
[image]

What I actually get...
[image]

Comment: Might be something to do with permissions - Have you specified what User your scheduled task should run as?

Comment: yup and i'm the only user on the desktop anyways

Comment: The task is probably being run using a different current directory, _maybe C:\Windows\System32_, you may have to explicitly change directory to the location where it works manually, or ensure that full paths to all files are stipulated within the script. _This is obviously an educated guess since you've not provided any of your commands or the script which is causing you concern_.

Comment: how would i go about doing that @Compo ?

Comment: Post the script by adding it as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46561391/edit) to your question, _not as a comment_.